# Using an array of strings with spaces in bash - error messages "curl: could not resolve host"

Tags: bash, scripting, curl, error-handling

I am attempting to write a script in bash that monitors certain aspects of a server, and sends a message to slack if it notices that something is wrong. However, I am running into a strange set of error messages that leads me to believe the syntax of my script is a little off. Here is the code in question:

```
message=("Please go to this website: www.google.com" "Please go to this website: www.github.com" "Please go to this website: www.wikipedia.com")

for j in seq `0 2`; do
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"<!channel>  '${message[$j]}' "}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/AN_ID/ANOTHER_ID/SOME_ID# Slack with channel mention
done
```

When I run this code, it should send a message to the specified slack group, stating each of the specified lines of text, for example "@channel Please go to this website: www.google.com"

When I run this, I receive the following error messages:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: go
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: to
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: this
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: website:
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 34
invalid_payloadcurl: (6) Could not resolve host: go
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: to
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: this
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: website:
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 33
```

Does anybody have any insights on how to resolve these error messages? I am thinking it has something to do with the way I have written the array of strings, but I can't identify the issue.

Comment: What happens if you double quote the variable: `--data '{"text":"<!channel>  '"${message[$j]}"' "}'` ?

Comment: There is no need for backticks around the `seq` arguments. Use `\`seq 0 2\`` and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not due to the declaration of the array, but the way you access elements.
See [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084257/bash-array-with-spaces-in-elements)

So, to quote the original answer from SO:

```bsh
for ((i = 0; i < ${#message[@]}; i++))
do
    echo "${message[$i]}"
done
```

It works fine on my side

(Panki's suggestion is right, remove backtick around seq arguments. 
You can use `$(seq 0 2)` instead. However, this does not fix the issue)

Answer (score 0):

For readability, I would do this:

```
messages=(
    "first"
    "second"
    ...
)
curl_opts=(
    -X POST
    -H 'Content-type: application/json'
)
data_tmpl='{"text":"<!channel>  %s "}' 
url=https://hooks.slack.com/services/...

for msg in "${messages[@]}"; do
    curl "${curl_opts[@]}" --data "$(printf "$data_tmpl" "$msg")" "$url" 
done
```